# glDrawArrays with cocos2d not drawing at all

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x, opengl-3

I have a lot of points that i need to draw in a batch and i have been trying it for two days and i cant seem get any progress with glDrawArrays. I have tried DrawNode and drawing each individual point for testing and it works correctly... but i cant seem to get `glDrawArray` to give any visual result.

Here is my drawing code(changed a few variable names):

```
auto glProgram = getGLProgram();
if (glProgram == nullptr) {
    setGLProgramState(GLProgramState::getOrCreateWithGLProgramName(
            GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_COLOR));
    glProgram = getGLProgram();
    if (glProgram == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
}
glProgram->use();
glProgram->setUniformsForBuiltins();

GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION | GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_COLOR);
GLfloat *vertices = new GLfloat[myStruct->data.size()*2];
GLfloat *colors   = new GLfloat[myStruct->data.size()*4];
int vIndex = 0;
int cIndex = 0;
for (std::vector<myPointStruct*>::iterator it = myStruct->data.begin(); it != myStruct->data.end(); ++it) {
    vertices[vIndex++] = (*it)->pos.x;
    vertices[vIndex++] = (*it)->pos.y;
    colors[cIndex++] = (*it)->color.r;
    colors[cIndex++] = (*it)->color.g;
    colors[cIndex++] = (*it)->color.b;
    colors[cIndex++] = (*it)->color.a;
glLineWidth(10);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), &colors[0]);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (GLsizei) myStruct->data.size());
CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWN_BATCHES_AND_VERTICES(1,  (GLsizei) myStruct->data.size());
```

And here is how i call the method:

```
_renderTexture->begin();
myMethodForDrawing();
_renderTexture->end();
Director::getInstance()->getRenderer()->render();
```

I have also tried:

```
_renderTexture->begin();
_customCommand.init(_renderTexture->getGlobalZOrder());
_customCommand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(MyClass:: myMethodForDrawing,this);
auto renderer = Director::getInstance()->getRenderer();
renderer->addCommand(&_customCommand);
_renderTexture->end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The 5th paramter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes. If `stride` is 0, the generic vertex attributes are understood to be tightly packed in the array.

Since your vertices and colors are tightly packed, you do not need to set the stride parameter. Note, `sizeof(GLfloat)` is wrong anyway. In you case it would be `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)` for `vertices` and `4 * sizeof(GLfloat)` for `colors`.

Change your code like this (focus on the `0` for the 5th parameter):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertices[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &colors[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had tried that before as well, it still doesnt seem to show anything... Is there any other issue with the code? Or is there a way to see if it is drawing but not in front? Or on top of another canvas object? I'm kind of lost on how to debug this if the code is correct.

Comment: @TaimoorAbdullahKhan In your code there is no further obvious issue. But there can be tons of issues. Try to disable the depth test `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`. On other popular issue would be the projection matrix. May be your geometry is to small for the projection or is outside the clipspace.

Comment: I'll look these up one by one and check them.